# How to put object tags on existing tagged object

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda

I am currently developing Lambda functions using NodeJS and AWS S3 SDK.

While working local with serverless offline, I can easily replace an object TagSet with `putObjectTagging` function, but in Production environment, I do have this error:

> Cannot provide multiple Tags with the same key

While reading `putObjectTagging` and AWS tags documentation, I do not find any solution for this error because I do presume that `putObjectTagging` replace all tags of an existing object.

In my code, I get the existing TagSet and update the values, then put them:

```
let tags = await S3.getObjectTagging(bucketParam).promise();
// process on tags and set in paramsPutObjectTagging
await S3.putObjectTagging(paramsPutObjectTagging).promise();
```

Thank you in advance,
Regards.

Comment: As the AWS documentation says : 

> PUT Object tagging – Replaces tags on an object. You specify tags in the request > body. There are two distinct scenarios of object tag management using this API.
> - Object has no tags – Using this API you can add a set of tags to an object (the >object has no prior tags).
> - Object has a set of existing tags – To modify the existing tag set, you must >first retrieve the existing tag set, modify it on the client side, and then use >this API to replace the tag set.

Answer (score 0):

The `s3:PutObjectTagging` call will replace any existing `TagSet` on the object with the `TagSet` provided in the call. Although the `TagSet` attribute in the request body for the call is an array, the `Key` attribute of every item in the array must be distinct, you cannot have duplicate `Key`s in the `TagSet`.

To add a new tag to an object whilst preserving the existing tags that are there you need to retrieve the existing `TagSet` using `s3:GetObjectTagging`, then append the new tag to the `TagSet` array, then use `s3:PutObjectTagging` as described above. When doing this you need to check that there isn't already a tag in the `TagSet` retrieved from `s3:GetObjectTagging` with the same `Key` as the new tag you're trying to add - this is likely to be why you are getting that error.